# Unix regex get only the first match

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I have the following text:

NodeMetaData **MapNodeId="105141"** PageFormat="OsXml" UniqueIdentifier="fd0f9ade-88e1-4b04-b338-0a8884f66423" RelativePath="Test_03/AddressMap_MyAddressMap.os.xml" LastPulledRevision="-9223372036854775808" LastPulledMd5="" LastSyncedMd5="7D0C294B9A7C09F17FD5AC0414179DD414649455297B8F73125D7FB5E39D647D" HasMergeConflicts="false" 
  NodeMetaData **MapNodeId="105142"** Pag
  eFormat="OsXml" UniqueIdentifier="85f55c40-f95c-47f2-9c97-d35881e8f762" RelativePath="Test_03/Struct_MyStruct.os.xml" LastPulledRevision="-922337203685477580
  8" LastPulledMd5="" LastSyncedMd5="32364BCCBCD8AA9C47D8E09A3EB06667DD9476EB155F9411FA359EFA5C1A4F4F" HasMergeConflicts="false"

There are two MapNodeId (see bold) and I need to get only the first one and insert it to a file.
I used the following:

```
set WorkingCopyRI=`( sed -n 's/.*MapNodeId=\"// ; s/\" .*//p' Result.log)`
```

but the var contains the the id of both MapNodeId, what do I need to add in order to get only the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You can append `;T;q` to your script to make it quit after the second `s` instruction prints for the first time.

Here's a cleaner and more robust way to do the whole thing:

```
sed -n '/MapNodeId=/ { s/^.*\sMapNodeId="\([^"]*\)"\s .*$/\1/p; q }'
```

I'm assuming your ID-s won't contain double quotes -- if they can, you will have to modify the expression in group #1.

(Also, your formatting gives no clue as to whether your text occurs in multiple lines or not, but I'm assuming that the `MapNodeId="..."` parts appear on separate lines, otherwise you wouldn't have this problem.)

Answer (score 0):

***perl*** approach:

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /MapNodeId="([^"]+)"/' Result.log
```

The output:

```
105141
```

---

`print "$1\n"` - print the first captured group value

---

Or if you have ***grep*** *PCRE* support:

```
grep -Po '.*MapNodeId="\K([^"]+)' Result.log | head -n 1
```